# New page in Blazor project

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor

I created a page within a subdirectory called "Condominioo" and I need to add a link in the "NavMenu.razor" file so that when it is activated it calls the new page created.

[image]

When I click on the link, an error appears: Error: 404

Comment: You should paste the code as a snippet directly into your post instead of an image of the code

Answer (score 1):

In modern Blazor apps to create a new page you should be using `Razor Components` (.razor) instead of the older MVC Razor Page/View `.cshtml' - Classic Razor Pages...

[image]

In a Razor component we can use the `@page` directive to designate that component as a page and to define the route to access the page:

```
@page "/index"

<PageTitle>My New Page</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

It doesn't matter what the *physical* path to that file is, I could put this in any subfolder of the project and still access it via the route defined in the directive.

The NavLink to this would look like:

```
<NavLink href="index">Index</NavLink>
```

You can define complex routes if you want to, but the route you define is not tied to the physical location of the file, to make you existing nav link work, define your route as this:

```
@page "/Condominioo/Index.cshtml"
```

It doesn't make a lot of sense to do that, but it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should create Razor component files with the `.razor` extension, not `.cshtml`. The `.cshtml` extension is used for Razor Pages and MVC views in ASP.NET Core which are different from Blazor components

To define a route in a `.razor` file, you use the `@page` directive at the top of the file. For example, if you have a `MyPage.razor` in the SomeFolder, you would start the file with `@page "/path"` or `@page "/parentpath1/path"`.

As per your example picture

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/condominioo/Index"

<h3>My Custom Page</h3>
<p>This is my custom page content.</p>
```

**NavMenu.razor**

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="/condominioo/Index">
    <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> My Custom Page
</NavLink>
```

**[Check Out this Small Tutorial it might help you a lot](https://blazor-university.com/routing/)**